# asp.net implementar jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realmente frustrado con esta situación:

tengo este código en un archivo `html` el cual usa librerías de `jquery` para hacer `autocomplete` en un `textbox` de la información que tengamos en el source y funciona como debe ser

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: ['choice1', 'choice2']
});
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

El problema es cuando quiero pasar ese código a `asp.net` `mvc`, realmente no hace nada. Tengo este otro código de `jquery` cuya función es pasar el valor de un `textbox` a otro `textbox` totalmente implementado en `asp`, es decir, supongo que ya tengo una idea de como implementar código `jquery` en `asp`, este es el código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#codigoCompany").change(function () {
        var codigo = $("#codigoCompany").val();
        $("#txtCliente").val(codigo);
    })
})
```

El codigo de autocompletar es este:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#codigoCompany").autocomplete({
        source: ['choice1', 'choice2']
        });
    });
```

Y ni siquiera dejándolo exactamente como este en el `html` de arriba he podido lograr que funcione, no tengo idea de que esta pasando... 
tendría que ponerlo en `window.onload`???

Esta es mi vista create

```
  @model Prueba_concepto.factura
  @*@model Prueba_concepto.cliente*@

  @{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=selector]:radio").click(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == 'directo') {

            $('#lecturaInicial').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#lecturaFinal').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#codigo').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#galones').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#precio').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#flete').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloDescarga1').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloDescarga2').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloDescarga3').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloManhole1').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloManhole2').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#selloManhole3').attr("disabled", false);


            $('#lecturaInicial').hide();
            $('#lecturaFinal').hide();
            $('#selloDescarga1').show();
            $('#selloDescarga2').show();
            $('#selloDescarga3').show();
            $('#selloManhole1').show();
            $('#selloManhole2').show();
            $('#selloManhole3').show();



        } else if ($(this).val() == 'medidor') {
            $('#selloDescarga1').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#selloDescarga2').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#selloDescarga3').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#selloManhole1').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#selloManhole2').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#selloManhole3').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#lecturaInicial').removeAttr("disabled", false);
            $('#lecturaFinal').removeAttr("disabled", false);
            $('#codigo').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#galones').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#precio').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#flete').attr("disabled", false);

            $('#lecturaInicial').show();
            $('#lecturaFinal').show();
            $('#selloDescarga1').hide();
            $('#selloDescarga2').hide();
            $('#selloDescarga3').hide();
            $('#selloManhole1').hide();
            $('#selloManhole2').hide();
            $('#selloManhole3').hide();

        }
    });
});




window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 1;
    canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#30329b";


};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#codigoCompany").autocomplete({
            source: "/Factura/buscarCodigo"
        });
    });
})




var canvas,
    ctx,
    flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;


function color(obj) {
    switch (obj.id) {
        case "green":
            x = "green";
            break;
        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
        case "yellow":
            x = "yellow";
            break;
        case "orange":
            x = "orange";
            break;
        case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }
    if (x == "white") y = 14;
    else y = 2;
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";


        document.getElementById("firma").value = dataURL.slice(22);
    });
});



function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == "down") {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == "up" || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == "move") {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<h2>Conduce</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Facturas", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") } })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fichaCamion, "fichaCamion", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("fichaCamion", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.fichaCamion, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.fichaCamion)*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fichaCamion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cliente, "cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("cliente", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.codigoCompany, "Codigo Cliente", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.codigoCompany, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.codigoCompany, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("cliente codigo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.codigoCompany, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

            @Html.TextBox("txtCliente", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firma, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firma, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "" } })
        </div>
    </div>


    <canvas id="c" width="500" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;margin-left:200px"></canvas><br />

    <img id="canvasimg" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:52%;display:inline;" />


    <input type="button" value="save" id="btn" size="30" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:10%;" />

    @*<input type="button" value="guardar firma" id="btn-server" size="30" onclick="save()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;" />*@


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.foto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <span class="btn btn-default">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.imageFile, new { Type = "file" })
                @*<input type="file" name="imageFile" required />*@
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.horaEntrada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.horaEntrada, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.horaEntrada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.horaSalida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.horaSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.horaSalida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="margin-left:200px">
                    Seleccionar metodo de entrega
                </legend>
                <input type="radio" name="selector" value="directo" style="margin-left:200px" />  Directo<br />
                <input type="radio" name="selector" value="medidor" style="margin-left:200px" />  Medidor<br />

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lecturaInicial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lecturaInicial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "true", @Value = ViewBag.remanente } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lecturaInicial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>

    </div>





    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />



        </div>
    </div>

</div>
 }

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

}
```

Este es el controlador Facturas

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using Prueba_concepto.Models;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using Rotativa;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace Prueba_concepto.Controllers
{
public class FacturasController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Quickbooks Data; OLE DB Services=-2");


    // GET: Facturas
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {




                var factura = db.factura.Include(f => f.camion).Include(f => f.cliente1);
                return View(factura.ToList());

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public JsonResult buscarCodigo(string term)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            //OdbcCommand query = new OdbcCommand("select name from customer where companyName ="+ term);
            //return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            var resultado = db.cliente.Where(x => x.name.Contains(term)).Select(x => x.apellido).ToList();

            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    // GET: Facturas/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        //Por alguna razon me da error cuando desea acceder al controlaro si el if del login cuenta con un ||
        //Por lo que debo de poner un try-catch
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                factura factura = db.factura.Find(id);
                if (factura == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(factura);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public ActionResult PDF_details(int id)
    {


        var x = db.factura.Find(id);
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("pdf", x);
    }

    public ActionResult pdf(int id)
    {
       // factura factura = db.factura.Find(id);
        var model = db.factura.Find(id);
        return View("pdf", model);
    }

    public JsonResult BuscarCliente(string term)
    {
        string query = "select name from customer where companyName =" + term;
        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }








    // GET: Facturas/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                ViewBag.fichaCamion = new SelectList(db.camion, "id", "camion1");
                ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.cliente, "id", "compania");
                ViewBag.remanente = db.camion.Find(1).remanente;

                return View();

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            throw;
        }
    }

    // POST: Facturas/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,fecha,fichaCamion,cliente,prueba,foto,horaEntrada,horaSalida,lecturaInicial,lecturaFinal,codigo,galones,precio,flete,selloDescarga1,selloDescarga2,selloDescarga3,selloManhole1,selloManhole2,selloManhole3")] factura factura)
    //public ActionResult Create(imagen view)
    public ActionResult Create(factura factura)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string pic = string.Empty;
                    string folder = "~/Content/imagenes";
                    string folderFirma = "~/Content/firmas";


                    Image firma = Upload(factura.firma);

                    factura.firmaImage = firma;


                    string firmaImageName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm") + ".jpg";
                    string ruta2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folderFirma), firmaImageName);

                    factura.firmaImage.Save(ruta2);

                    if (factura.lecturaFinal != null)
                    {
                        decimal? remanente = factura.lecturaInicial - factura.lecturaFinal;

                        db.camion.Find(1).remanente = remanente;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decimal? remanente = db.camion.Find(1).remanente;

                        db.camion.Find(1).remanente = remanente - factura.galones;
                    }


                    //factura.firma = "~/Content/firmas/hello2.jpg";
                    factura.firma = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderFirma, firmaImageName);

                    //  siguiendo la ruta

                    pic = Path.GetFileName(factura.imageFile.FileName);

                    string ruta = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folder), pic);

                    factura.imageFile.SaveAs(ruta);


                    pic = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, pic);



                    factura.foto = pic;

                    //OdbcCommand query = new OdbcCommand("select name from customer where ");


                    db.factura.Add(factura);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");

                }

                ViewBag.fichaCamion = new SelectList(db.camion, "id", "camion1", factura.fichaCamion);
                ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.cliente, "id", "compania", factura.cliente1);
                return View(factura);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

            //return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            //throw;
        }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Image Upload(string firma)
    {
        string converted = firma.Replace('-', '+');
        converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;


        //string folder2 = "~/Content/firmas/";
        //string pic = "fileFirma.png";

        //string ruta = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folder2), pic);

        //string localFileName = "filename.png";
        //string filePath = Path.Combine(folder2, localFileName);



      //  File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(firma));

        //Image image;
        //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        //{
        //    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        //    image.Save(ruta, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        //}

        //return ruta;
    }



    // GET: Facturas/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                }
                factura factura = db.factura.Find(id);
                if (factura == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                ViewBag.fichaCamion = new SelectList(db.camion, "id", "camion1", factura.fichaCamion);
                ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.cliente, "id", "name", factura.cliente);
                return View(factura);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            throw;
        }
    }

    // POST: Facturas/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,fecha,fichaCamion,cliente,prueba,foto,horaEntrada,horaSalida,lecturaInicial,lecturaFinal,codigo,galones,precio,flete,selloDescarga1,selloDescarga2,selloDescarga3,selloManhole1,selloManhole2,selloManhole3")] factura factura)
        public ActionResult Edit(factura factura)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin") || Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Camionero"))
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(factura).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                ViewBag.fichaCamion = new SelectList(db.camion, "id", "camion1", factura.fichaCamion);
                ViewBag.cliente = new SelectList(db.cliente, "id", "name", factura.cliente);
                return View(factura);

            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            }

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
            throw;
        }
    }

    // GET: Facturas/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin"))
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            factura factura = db.factura.Find(id);
            if (factura == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(factura);

        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
        }
    }

    // POST: Facturas/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        if (Session["Id"] != null && Session["Rol"].ToString().Equals("Admin"))
        {
            factura factura = db.factura.Find(id);
            db.factura.Remove(factura);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Recuerde haber iniciado sección o no tiene los permisos para ver esta información");
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿En qué momento llamas al servidor para obtener los valores del autocompletado?

Comment: En ningun momento, simplemente toma la info del source que aqui seria choice1 o choice 2 (es esto debido a que estoy haciendo pruebas), si fuera al servidor seria source: "Facturas/buscarCodigo" y el metodo buscarCodigo recibiria un string term y el codigo de este metodo seria algo parecido a esto: using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {  var resultado = db.cliente.Where(x => x.name.Contains(term)).Select(x => x.apellido).ToList();

                return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

Comment: Creo que no me dejo entender, tampoco estoy entendiendo lo que quieres lograr. En ningún lado de la pregunta hay código aspnet mvc. Solo javascript, jquery y HTML. Esto me confunde: `El problema es cuando quiero pasar ese código a asp.net mvc, realmente no hace nada` y Código  ASPnet MVC inexistente.

Comment: lo lamento, ahora mismo lo pongo